# How can I make a Google spreadsheet Function reference one column's value and adjust it to a different Value?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, worksheet-function

I am trying to create a spreadsheet that will calculate varying sizes. I need it to reference a key where a letter is an established size such as H=1984, S=672, etc. so as that that column can be changed between a series of letters and the formula will automatically convert the equation.

### Example:

```
     A       |     B      |    C     |         D         
Type One     |     H      |    94    |   (C1/B1) = 0.047
Type Two     |     S      |   115    |   (C2/B2) = 0.171
```

Where as if I switch H to S the formula will automatically change the value and I receive the correct computation.

```
     A       |     B      |    C     |         D         
Type One     |     S      |    94    |   (C1/B1) = 0.14
Type Two     |     S      |   115    |   (C2/B2) = 0.171
```

Do I have to make a key section that the formula will reference from depending on what is in the cells?

Comment: Haven't you been able to find a similar solution here on Web Applications?

Answer (score 1):

Say create a table with `H` in G1, `S` in G2, `1984` in H1 and `672` in H2. In D1:

```
=C1/vlookup(B1,G:H,2,0)
```

and copy down should suit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a lookup table where the values for H and S etc. are next to the letters. Then you can use a lookup function to retrieve the values. The lookup function can be nested in a formula.

Comment: Could you add some example code to your answer?